# With tumblr themes, do I put anything between the variables in the html?

Tags: html, css, variables, tumblr

What I mean is, okay, I know basic html and CSS. I know you can put tumblr's variable of `{Title}` in the `<title>` tags in the head section.

I understand that with tumblr variables, you make these visible by putting them in your code.

So you put them in `<body>` such as

```
{block:Posts}DOES ANYTHING NEED TO BE BETWEEN HERE?{/block:Posts}
```

or do I just insert the variables and then wrap them with a class so we can edit them via CSS?

Comment: Kinda. You use tumblr variables along with html to create the markup. `<a href="{Permalink}">{lang:Permalink}</a>`

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types of code that are unique to tumblr. Blocks and variables.

Variables are like `{Title}` and they are essentially place holders.

Blocks are like the second example you have, eg. `{block:Posts}` `{\block:Posts}`. Blocks are used to conditionally render code. The posts block will render the code in-between it for all posts, just as `{block:Photo}` `{/block:Photo}` will only render the code within it for photo posts.

Another handy example is `{block:PermalinkPage}` `{/block:PermalinkPage}`. This will only render the code between it on individual posts' permalink pages and is helpful for conditionally displaying the posts' notes etc.

You can find a description of all the different blocks (and variables) and under what circumstances they show the code within them in the [tumblr documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your content needs to be withing the  tags. Between your {block:Posts} you need to include blocks for each type of posts.

The best thing to do is to look for base theme codes. These will give you a very basic layout that you can play around with, and all of the relevant code will be there. It's much easier to learn this way, then in the future, you can start writing themes from scratch.

Hope that helps.